# Definitive android screen sizes

Tags: android, screens

I have looked at the pages here on stackoverflow regarding this issue and followed up by looking at the links provided as some of the answers provided but I am still very confused. I use Photoshop to develop my screen shots in my android apps. It breaks down to this, there are four folders in the res folder for the different phone types Small Medium Large X-Large.
If I want to create an image to be used as a background that fills in the background completely and I am creating that image in the default resolution on Photoshop of 72 pixels per inch, what methodology and dimensions should I use for each image?

The specification I use in the manifest file would be set up as fill parent for both width and height.

I do understand there are many types of phones with different screen sizes but I need the most generic

As I understand it the images will be resized to fit screens but I that in itself leads to the creation of strange images if the original is not originally setup to be somewhat close.

So I need the somewhat close dimensions of a typical background image for each folder.

Small  ->   X_Dim x Y_Dim

Medium  ->   X_Dim x Y_Dim

Large  ->   X_Dim x Y_Dim

X-Large  ->   X_Dim x Y_Dim

Four folders four sets of dimensions

Again I am using Photoshop and 72 pixel/inch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screen sizes are different concept with screen dpis

So, based on your question the most generic screen resolution for each dpi are:

ldpi 240 x 320px

mdpi 320 x 480px

hdpi 480 x 800px

xhdpi 720 x 1280px

I am talking about the generic screen resolution that each ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi commonly has, so if you could create assets with these four sizes, it will fit most devices.

Comment: for detailed info refer http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thank you very much. The data out there is very confusing